# Problem with double click on checkbox with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11

I would like to disable the double click on checkboxes on internet explorer. The double click causes errors on the function (only on internet explorer 11).

```
 $('#editArchivesTable tbody').on('click', "input[type=checkbox]", function () { alreadySelected = $('#editArchivesTable tbody').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').parent('td').parent('tr').attr('choix(dataTable.row($(this).parent('td').parent('tr')).index(), $(this).is(':checked'))
});




$("#editArchivesTable tbody").bind('dblclick', "input[type=checkbox]", (function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}));
```

I'm waiting for my function choix not to be triggered when double clicking

[For example, when double clicking on a checkbox, the value "85" is inserted twice in my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AukO6.png)

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: I added a picture on the post. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `click` event, use the `change` event.

In the `change` event check the **state** of the checkbox.

If it is checked, add the value to the array. If not, remove it from the array.